# Array subscript operator on Vectors

Tags: c++, vector

I was writing a code to tokenize a string wrt delimeters ",".

```
    void Tokenize(const string& str, vector<string>& tokens, const string& delimeters)
    {
      // Skip delimiters at beginning.
      string::size_type lastPos = str.find_first_not_of(delimiters, 0);
      // Find first "non-delimiter".
      string::size_type pos     = str.find_first_of(delimiters, lastPos);

      while (string::npos != pos || string::npos != lastPos)
      {
         // Found a token, add it to the vector.
         tokens.push_back(str.substr(lastPos, pos - lastPos));
         // Skip delimiters.  Note the "not_of"
         lastPos = str.find_first_not_of(delimiters, pos);
         // Find next "non-delimiter"
        pos = str.find_first_of(delimiters, lastPos);
      }
    }

    int main()
    {
       string str;
       int test_case;
       cin>>test_case;
       while(test_case--)
       {
           vector<string> tokens;
           getline(cin, str);
           Tokenize(str, tokens, ",");
           // Parsing the input string 
           cout<<tokens[0]<<endl;
       }
       return 0;
    }
```

It gives segmentation fault on running. When I debugged it the line

```
    cout<<tokens[0]<<endl
```

was the cause of problem.I can't understand why because at [cplusplus.com](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/vector/operator%5b%5d/) it uses the [ ] operartors for accesing the values of vectors

Comment: When you run the program, does `tokens` have any elements?  If not, then there is no element at index `0` to be accessed.

Comment: You're probably accessing memory that has yet to be created internally in Vector<>. This will happen when you push something to your instance of vector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
cin>>test_case; // this leaves a newline in the input buffer
while(test_case--)
{
    vector<string> tokens;
    getline(cin, str); // already found newline
    Tokenize(str, tokens, ",");  // passing empty string
```

Without looking at your Tokenize function, I would guess that an empty string results in an empty vector, which means when you print `tokens[0]`, that element does not actually exist.  You need to make sure your input buffer is empty before you call `getline`.  You could put a call to `cin.ignore()` right after your number input, for example.

You could also forgo `operator>>`, and only use getline.  Then do string to number conversions with your favorite method.

Answer (score 1):

Is it possible that the read using `std::getline()` wasn't successful? In this case the string would be empty and using the subscript operator would crash. You should always test whether reading was successful **after** trying to read, e.g.:

```
if (std::getline(std::cin, str)) {
    // process the read string
}
```